# Copy all files from Source to Destination Java

Tags: java, directory, path, copy

I have to code a java method public void public void copyTo(Path rSource, Path rDest) that copies all files from existing directory rSource to a new directory rDest with the same name. rSource must exist and rDest must not exist, runtime exception if not true. I can't seem to make it work, help!

What I tried :

```
public void copyTo(Path rSource, Path rDest){
    if(!(Files.exists(rSource) && Files.isDirectory(rSource)) || (Files.exists(rDest))){
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    try {
        Files.createDirectory(rDest);
        if(Files.exists(rDest)){
            try(DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(rSource)) {
                for(Path p : stream) {
                    System.out.println(p.toString());
                    Files.copy(p, rDest);
                }
            } catch( IOException ex) {
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I highly recommend you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). This will help you to improve the quality of your questions. **For every question, please show the attempts you have tried and the error messages you get from your attempts.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files.copy() at least takes two parameters, source and destination files path or stream. The problem in your case is that you are passing rDest folder Path, not the actual file Path. Just modify the code inside your for loop to append the files name from the source to the destination folder Path:

```
Path newFile = Paths.get(rDest.toString() + "/" + p.getFileName());
Files.copy(p, newFile);
```

Correct me if I'm wrong